# Simulating urban land use change using a Cellular Automata - Markov Model in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, cellular-automata

I am trying to simulate urban land use change using a Cellular Automata - Markov Model.

Is it possible to do this in ArcGIS (or any ArcGIS extension)?

I do not have access to IDRISI. I am fine with using any ArcGIS extension or other free software. My urban data has 5-7 land use classes that I need to simulate for. The output should be in map form.